# How can I change 'default' name and company when installing a software?

Tags: windows-7

When I'm installing some software, it requires me to enter name and company.
Then the 'default' name which 'was' same as my account name (of Windows 7) appears.
The account name was misspelled, so I recently changed it (including folder name and registry)
I think I completed all the steps to change the account name.
But old name still appears when installing a software.
How can I change this to my new account name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run regedit.exe, and navigate to the following location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ Windows NT \ CurrentVersion
```

To change the name of the registered owner, double-click `RegisteredOwner`.

Under `Value` data, type the name that you want, and then click OK.

**Source:**

http://windowsxp.mvps.org/owner.htm