# How to change company name in Windows?

Tags: windows, user-accounts

I recently bought a new computer, an HP, but something weird is happening. Every time I install some software that has a “Company” field, it automatically fills it with “Hewlett-Packard”. While the computer is HP, that doesn't mean I work for HP. Is there a way I can change this to a company I really work for?

Comment: Is the downvote because it's a duplicate?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez - That is a safe assumption.

Comment: @Ramhound, but unfair, in my opinion.

Comment: I don't see how that justification would be unfair.The question already exists, one expectation we have here at Superuser, is before asking a question some basic research is done. By doing some level of research, you can verify that, an existing question does not already exist already and thus avoid a situation like this. I searched for this [topic](https://www.bing.com/search?q=change+company+name+in+windows&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN) in a Google search, the first result, was this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/595692/how-can-i-change-default-name-and-company-when-installing-a-software).

Comment: @Ramhound - You searched "in a Google search" using Bing?

Comment: @Steven - Doesn't everyone?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows XP and newer you can change this text within the registry. Start `regedit` and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`. Look for the entry `RegisteredOrganization` and change that to your liking.

Comment: Steven's comment points to the exact same answer, this is a duplicate.